# Check Project Dependencies

Tags: vb.net, dependencies

I have a VB.Net project with a number of my own written class libraries, which are set as dependencies to my program.

What I would like to do is check to see if the respective DLL's exist in the application's folder, before it goes through its startup routine. In short, the startup routine reads from a serialized database file into an object. This object is then used all around the program for various forms of data-storage. What I found was if a dependency was accidentally deleted, the program would start and generate the unhandled exception error. If you pressed "quit" the program would terminate, but it would also corrupt the serialized database file. I'd like to prevent this by doing a check to see if the file exists. If the file doesn't exist, it would notify you, and pressing okay would terminate the project, but in a safe way as to not corrupt the database.

I was able to find something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108346/checking-for-external-dependances-in-vb-net) but this seems to just be an external dll file. My project actually has sub-projects which generate each file.

I have a feeling it's not possible, because rather than an external dll, the dll's are actually used for the program. It won't be able to run without them, and hence, won't be able to execute code without them. However, I'd like to just make sure with someone that is more experienced than I am.

Edit:
One way I could see doing it is to have a "launcher"-type of program. This file will check if all the files exist, and only if they do, the main executable would be run. However, I'd like to try and avoid having multiple exe's if at all possible.

Comment: why? once they are installed, they are there.  if one gets deleted, it is user stupidity, but they can reinstall.  You do know the external references, so just add then to a list and run `FileExist` against it.

Comment: For some reason, the code under the form_load event does not seem to execute before that exception is thrown. Is there any place I can place the FileExist code?

Comment: what does this mean: `rather than an external dll, the dll's are actually used for the program`

Comment: My apologies. I meant to say that these dll's were class libraries. I added them to my project, then added them as project dependencies.

Comment: do they contain something like subclassed controls?  usercontrols?  something used on the form like a component?  those would get referenced when the form is instanced

Comment: They store images that are used in the program. I have the main executable (which is frequently updated). So I decided to throw the images into their own class library because they are never really updated. My form_load event calls functions in these libraries to make sure that the no outdated versions are being used.

Comment: this makes no sense.  if the serialized file gets trashed, it presumably happens after the form load code kicks things off.  that does not jive with `the code under the form_load event does not seem to execute before the exception` .  did you add the check for files to exist before the existing code?  You could move it all to a new procedure `StartApp`, add the files test in the load then only call StartApp if they are all there.  or start from `Sub Main` before there is a form.

Comment: Yup! That's why I'm confused. When I get the exception, the database file gets corrupted, which means that it must have been opened. However, I added a msgbox("Here!") at the top of the form_load event. This message box does not display, but I still do get the exception and file still gets corrupted.

Comment: I do think it might be best to follow your advice. I think you mean something similar to this? http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/MainRoutine01.htm

Comment: are you sure you you have the right form as form main?  if it is working like you say, then something is firing before the form is loading - are they table adapters and stuff in the component tray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Form Load code results in references to these externals, change the project to start from a sub Main:  `Project Properties -> Application -> StartUp Object -> Sub Main`

Add a module, and a sub main (or add a Sub main to an existing module):

```
Public Sub Main()
    ' check for file exist on list of files here

    ' turn on styles
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()

    ' start message pump
    Application.Run(New frmMain)         ' use your form name
                                    ' the form load will run at this point
End Sub
```

Presumably, you'd show what files are missing in a messagebox or something **and exit**.  This would be useful if a class library included a control that was used on the form - you could test for it before the form is created.  Frankly users that poke around and delete files get what they deserve.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I can now run the checks before I call the main form which uses the dependencies. Thank you!